# Net Core Can application have Both Repository and DAO Data Access Object Pattern?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, repository, domain-driven-design, asp.net-core-2.0

I read Repositories should NOT utilize IQueryable. Simple repository example have ListAll, FindById, Add, Delete. Below is a sample Product Repository ListAll. If I cannot overlay queries, and require searching queries eg, ProductTable by Category, or ProductTable by Weight (intricate queries), I will then require a DAO (Data Access Object Pattern).

So question is,

(a) is it okay to have a Repository Pattern and DAO Pattern in same application?

(b) Doesn't this bypass the whole point of having a DDD Repository Pattern?

How would I access ProductTable having Intriciate requests while still going through repository? The first Repository query will be slow.

```
public virtual IEnumerable<Products> List()
{
    return _dbContext.Products.AsEnumerable();
}

// This repository pattern will be slow, first it access all product and Then filters

var result = context.products()
               .Where(o => o.ProductCategoryId== 5);


// This is dao pattern, with more specific queries

var result = context.products.AsEnumerable()
               .Where(o => o.ProductCategoryId== 5);
```

[Entity Framework Repository Pattern why not return Iqueryable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33755499/entity-framework-repository-pattern-why-not-return-iqueryable)

https://deviq.com/repository-pattern/

Comment: you can use specification approach as used [here](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnWeb/tree/master/src/ApplicationCore/Specifications)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ***repository*** is geared towards an aggregate.  It returns a fully constituted aggregate that you use mainly for transactional purposes.  Changes to your data are effected through the aggregates.  You should not *really* be querying aggregates as they may not be the best at returning the relevant/concise data.

A ***query*** layer is a *read model* that returns only the relevant data in as lightweight a mechanism as possible.  You *may* view this as a DAO but it isn't really the same thing although it most certainly is focused on **data** retrieval.

In that sense what you are proposing i.t.o. the two mechanisms isn't only viable but I would strongly recommend you go that route :)

Since the intention between the two mechanisms is so divergent having a query mechanism in no way diminishes the usefulness of a repository.